# I installed chruby/ruby-install on Ubuntu 20.04: cannot execute ruby from within bash-script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ruby

I have a ruby setup from here:

[installation_ruby](https://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you)

now when I run a gem inside of a bash-script I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: »ruby“: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

Diverse tips on the web with PATH variable or an rvm installation of ruby with the same error, did not help!

Do you have a clue?

BTW: gem running on CLI works just fine!

Comment: same error message after fresh install on WSL2 ubuntu 20.04.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know, what is happening: but after reboot ruby in bash script is working fine! Seems to be a "wackelkontakt"!